# Max heap memory of tomcat varies though it is fixed

Tags: tomcat

I am using Hyperic to monitor Tomcat applications.
 I have configured Tomcat max and min heap size to 8192m
But, my problem is hyperic showing max heap memory for tomcat which varies from-7.917GB to 7.945GB
Is really this memory changing? what mechanism behind assigning max heap memory to tomcat.

Comment: I think you are confusing GiB with GB. 7.917GiB is 8,300 MiB.

Comment: Thanks for reply,But it is GB only.And my question is about variation of that fixed value....?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of heap memory used will necessarily change as objects are allocated and garbage collected. There is no way to keep the amount absolutely constant unless no allocations or garbage collection occurs ever.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I think you are saying about "Heap memory used" ,defiantly that will vary,Here I am not saying about 'heap memory committed' or 'heap used' But I am asking about 'Heap memory Max' parameter....

Comment: As the heap memory changes, so will its maximum.

Comment: That means though I have configured -Xmx and -Xms to say value V,then according to need of application the 'max heap size' the tomcat actually using can vary up to limit V...?

Comment: Right. It would be absurdly hard to try to keep it at exactly the number you specified.